# How to write a bash script to detect a process with more than 0,0% CPU

Tags: bash

I want to make a script, to detect CPU % of process "coreaudiod"

When the process has >0,0% CPU, it should execute the script.

I tried suggestions found on this forum, but no luck:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i app_pid
declare -i app_cpu
declare -i cpu_limit
app_name="coreaudiod"
cpu_limit="1"
app_pid=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`
app_cpu=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $3*100}`
if [[ $app_cpu -gt $cpu_limit ]]; then
# Exit 0 for success, and non-zero for failure.
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Can someone please help me with the script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i app_cpu="`ps aux | awk '$11 == "/usr/sbin/coreaudiod" { print $3 * 100 }'`"
(( ! app_cpu ))
```

Alternatively, if you want to kill it directly from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i app_cpu="`ps aux | awk '$11 == "/usr/sbin/coreaudiod" { print $3 * 100 }'`"
if (( ! app_cpu )); then
    # Do something, such as kill the process:
    pkill -TERM coreaudiod
    sleep 1
    pkill -0 coreaudiod && pkill -KILL coreaudiod
fi
```